# Supporting older devices

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

On November 1st, 2018, Google play started requiring apps to target API Level 26 at a minimum. API level 26 is not terribly old, leaving a large number of potential users who are still using phones that do not support API level 26. I want to find a way to still support those older phones via Google play by uploading an apk file that targets a lower API level (say, 21). However, google play doesn't seem to let me do that. Is this something I should be able to do? If so, how?

According to this article, I should be able to offer multiple apk files: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#CreatingApks
I followed the method described in this youtube video to upload my apk's: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMl_oLlf_g0

However, it seems like no matter what I do, the play console tells me that the API-Level-21 APK must target at least API level 26. I'm stumped...

Comment: I think you can't support such devices via Google Play Store, you have to provide them the .apk file if you want them to use your app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still support older phones while compiling against the latest SDK version.

Google is requiring you to compile against at **minimum** SDK 26 which would be the `targetSdkVersion` in your gradle file.

To declare what version you want to minimum support you use the `minSdkVersion` in your gradle file too

Your gradle file would look something like this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
```

Comment: I was wondering why there were two fields...
It looks like that might have worked (was able to upload the file). Just need to wait a few hours to verify that I can install it on my android 7.0 device.